# Panning web map not working in WPF WebBrowers. Works in Internet Explorer

Tags: wpf, xaml, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

We have an intranet web GIS application which I am trying to embed in a WPF application using a WebBrowser control. The application is a proprietary solution from a third party vendor over which I have no control - it works very similar to Google Maps. On my desktop I have Internet Explorer 11 installed, and in Internet Explorer the web GIS works fine. When embedded in a WebBrowser control on a WPF form (.NET 4.5, VS2012) the map loads and will zoom with a roll of the mouse wheel, but will not pan when I try to drag it.

The WPF view is as simple as can be:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="TestWebBrowser" />
</Grid>
```

The code-behind is equally simple:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.TestWebBrowser.Navigate("http://myserver/map.aspx");
    }
```

I've tried setting the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\myapp.exe` (and the .vshost.exe variant) to various values without success.

If I change the URL to `http://maps.google.com`, I can pan the Google map, so I know the WebBrowser isn't fundamentally incapable of allowing drag events in my current configuration, but I can't change the source code of the web application itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a 32bit app you need to set the registry key in Wow6432Node node.

So your key will look like:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\myapp.exe

Comment: Nice idea - I hadn't thought to try that, but unfortunately it didn't make a difference. I also tried deleting my original registry keys for FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and pointed the browser to a URL that displays the user agent string. Without them it shows IE7, with them it shows IE11, so I know it's reading those keys correctly. I tried values of 0, 11000 and 11001. I also tried putting the map URL into compatibility view in IE, and panning still worked. Conclusion: the problem has nothing to do with compatibility view.